Issue with Table Reference Formulas in Google Sheets Breaking Table Structure
I am trying to create an order management table in Google Spreadsheets using a script (Google Apps Script).
When I set a formula containing a table reference (e.g. tableName[columnName]) in the last row of the table using the script, the last row falls outside the scope of the table.
After investigating, I found that the problem was not with the script but with the behavior of the table in the spreadsheet.
Is this a correct specification?
Steps to replicate the core part of the issue

In a Google Sheet, enter the headers "Column 1" and "Column 2" in the first row.
Select the range from A1 to C4, then select Format > Convert to Table from the menu to create a table.
Name the created table "table_1."
Input arbitrary values into "Column 1" of the table.
Manually enter =table_1[Column 1] into each cell in "Column 2" without using autofill suggestions.

Expected Behavior
Each cell in "Column 2" displays the value from the corresponding row in "Column 1."
Actual Behavior
The last row of the table is excluded from the table range, resulting in a #VALUE! error.

Before you set the expression in the last row of the table (row 4), the row is included in the table.

Setting the expression in the last row of the table removes the last row from the table's scope.
The error message displayed is as follows:

The default output of this reference is a single cell in the same row but a matching value could not be found. To get the values for the entire range use the ARRAYFORMULA function.


1, This scenario happens when you do not array enable a range in general & not something specific to Tables. This answer here explains it in a bit more detail 2, Also based on screenshot, the last row is not part of the table_1. you can test it by just using the formula ={table_1[Column 1]} somewhere else in the sheet

@rockinfreakshow
Thank you for your comment.
What I want to know is not the cause of the #VALUE! error, but why the last row of the table goes outside the table's range when the formula includes a table reference in that row.
To make the issue clearer, I’ve added a screenshot.

This seems to be an issue on Google side, you may try adding this as a bug here

@4thAnd1Thank you for letting me know who to contact. I will contact Google.

I think this is intentional (albeit undocumented) behaviour, and perhaps a recent change. What appears to be happening when you set a formula in the last row of a table for a column which has not already been autofilled with formulas from the top row, is that Sheets is assuming that you wish the last row of the table to be a footer row (this can be seen from the double line upper border for row 4 in your second screenshot). You then get the #VALUE! error because =table_1[Column 1] is trying to spill an array, but because you are declaring it from the footer row this is not allowed; footer row formulae must include some sort of aggregation so that only a single result is returned (e.g. =sum(table_1[Column 1]) is acceptable).
N.B. =table_1[Column 1] does not give an array result when declared in the body of the table because Sheets uses implicit intersection to return single results corresponding to the appropriate row of the array.
Table footer rows can be referenced using the [#TOTALS] syntax, but I don't recall this being mentioned when Sheets first implemented Tables so this is possibly a new phenomenon. Certainly previously the only way I was aware that footers could be added to Tables was via the older 'Alternating colours' formatting, which Tables still appear to use in the background.

I also suspect this is Google's specification but find the behavior inappropriate. In simple spreadsheets, it may not be significant, and autofill works as expected with table references in the last row.
Once a footer is set, it can't revert to a footerless table without reapplying the formatting. This is problematic with GAS that sets cell functions, as in my case. Reconstructing tables is unrealistic for users unfamiliar with spreadsheets.
Footers should be added via specific options, syntax, or menus. I plan to contact Google. Thank you for explaining.
